# Run-time error 13 when highlighting entire row

Tags: vba, excel

Whenever I try to highlight over column D I receive "Run-time error '13'". When I click debug it highlights this piece from the code, `If Target.Value = "Closed" Or Target.Value = "Closed" Then`. I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to fix this issue.

Edit*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim wsd As Worksheet
Dim wsc As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsd = Sheets("Pipeline")
Set wsc = Sheets("Closed")
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6:D65536")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target.Value = "Closed" Or Target.Value = "Closed" Then
erow = Target.Row
MsgBox "Moved to Closed"
numberofrow = wsc.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To numberofrow
If wsd.Cells(erow, 1) = wsc.Cells(i, 1) Then
Exit Sub
End If
Next

wsd.Range("A" & erow & ":A" & erow).EntireRow.Copy wsc.Range("A" &   numberofrow + 1)
With Target.Parent
  Union(.Range(.Cells(Target.Row, "A"), .Cells(Target.Row, "V")), _
      .Range(.Cells(Target.Row, "Y"), .Cells(Target.Row,    .Columns.Count))).ClearContents
`enter code here`End With
wsc.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:D" & numberofrow + 1).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Closed").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Closed").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C" &   numberofrow + 1), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Closed").Sort
.SetRange Range("A2:D" & numberofrow + 1)
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
wsd.Activate
End If
End If


End Sub
```

I had to piece a few things together in order to get this to work, which is why it's pretty ugly. I couldn't figure out where to put guard clause. This so far has worked for what I need it for (aside from the Run-time error), transferring accounts to a separate sheet based on the sales stage entered into column D. Again, I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Add a guard clause to your event handler: `If Target.Cells.Count = 1`.

Comment: Also, why have the same condition twice?

Comment: You need to improve your Worksheet_SelectionChange event macro so that it doesn't fire every time you do anything on the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler assumes only 1 cell is selected. When you highlight an entire column, `Target` represents all selected cells, and then `Target.Value` can't be meaningfully evaluated, so it raises a run-time error.

You need to modify your handler to remove that assumption, [as was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443891/run-time-error-13-when-highlighting-entire-row#comment72031421_42443891):

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

Presumably that event handler needs more tweaks to verify the `Target` is what the macro thinks/assumes it is, but given the information you've provided that would be it.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the entire code. Hopefully it will help

Comment: @Andy there was no need, the problem is the same - just add the above condition at the top of the procedure to bail out whenever `Target` contains more than a single cell. Does that not fix the issue?